# how to update mongoose specific values without getting other values converted to null?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, postman

im trying to update values in the collection, only way i got it to work is updating whole values together, if i update one value the rest of values gets null if exclude updating the file (image) i get error.

1)[upading whole values sucess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zbY1.png)

1-2))[mongoose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxJ98.png)

2) [when image excluded "Cannot read property 'originalname' of undefined"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOmFZ.png)

3)[when updating image only rest of values converted to null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85r5M.png)

**model**

```
const mongoose = require ("mongoose");
const user = require('../models/usermodel')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const sellerSchema= mongoose.model('seller',new mongoose.Schema({
image:{type:String,
    required:true}
password:{type:String,
          required:true}
lastName:{type:String,
          required:true}
name:{type:String,
      required:true}
numTel:{type:Number,
        required:true}
email:{type:String,
       required:true}
}))
module.exports = sellerSchema;
```

**control**

```
const sellermodel = require('../models/sellermodel');

var fs = require('fs');

const multer = require('multer');

const upload = multer({dest:__dirname +'/uploads/images'});

module.exports = {sellerupdate: function (req, res) {

sellermodel.updateOne({_id: req.params.id},

        {$set:{name:req.body.name,

        lastName:req.body.lastName,

        email:req.body.email,

        password:req.body.password,

        image:req.file.originalname,}},

        function (err,data) {

        if (err) {res.json({ msg: 'product not found'+err })
        }
        else {
          res.json({ msg: 'product updated successfully'+data} )
        }

    })
  }
}
```

**router**

```
 const sellercontrols = require("../controllers/sellercontrols");

 const router = require("express").Router();

 const multer = require('multer');

 const upload = multer({dest:__dirname + '/uploads/images/'});

 router.put('/update/:id',upload.single('image'),sellercontrols.sellerupdate);

 module.exports = router;
```

**server**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const sellerrouter= require('./routers/sellerrouter');

const db = require('./models/db');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({

extended: false }));

app.use("/seller",sellerrouter);

app.listen(8080,function(){

console.log('server is running')})
```

**please help**

Comment: Do u want to update `image` only? or whole document?

Comment: i want to update a single value without getting others converted to null

Comment: And that single value could be anything? or just `image`?

Comment: anything including image itself

Answer (score 1):

//This is the answer you've been looking for, I spent an hour trying to figure it. use this first syntax if email and password is inside an object else use the shorter one

```
const password = "new password";
const email = "new email"; 
let result = collection find({})
result  =  result.objectName
```

// now update email and password in the result object like this

```
result.email = email;
result.password = password
```

//after that send it back to the database

```
collection.updateOne({}, {$set: {fieldName: result}})
```

//and that's it or use this shorter one if its not in an object

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate({}, {$set: {email, password}})
```

if the email and password is inside an object use this

Answer (score 0):

This is easier said being done as you are  using `$set` and with that if you don't pass a value, it will default to `null` and in turn making your values in a document `null`. While you want to `update` multiple fields (could be 1 or 2 or whole document), you need to have a fail-save system so that for not changed values you keep the original ones.

This is how I would approach to this issue

1) Find the Document I want to update`(sellermodel.FindOne)`

2) Compare the `Object Returned` with `passed Object`, Updating the ones changed and keeping original if not changed (Hence solving `null` issues)

3) Update the `Object` with new values using `(sellermodel.updateOne)`

I'm assuming this would work but I didn't tested it, so you might have to change little bit here and there

```
    sellermodel.FindOne({_id: req.params.id},(err,item)=>{
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else{

       /* This will create a object with req.body and req.file (Assuming both are in JSON)*/
        let mergedObject= {...req.body,...req.file} 


        /* This will Compare Object from Mongoose and the object you passed and will update the values you passed 
        and keeping the orignal that were not changed*/
        let ObjectToUpdate=updateObjectValue(item,mergedObject) 

      /* Delete ObjectID otherwise it will throw an error */
         delete ObjectToUpdate._id
         delete ObjectToUpdate.__v


        /* After You have a perfect Object You can update the values  */
        sellermodel.updateOne({_id: req.params.id},ObjectToUpdate,(err,data)=>{
            if(err) {res.json({msg:'error occured'})}
            else{
                res.json({ msg: 'product updated successfully'+data})
            }
        })
    }

})

var updateObjectValue = (obj1, obj2) => {
    var destination = Object.assign({}, obj2);
    Object.keys(obj1).forEach(k => {
      if(k in destination) {
        destination[k] = obj1[k];
      }
    });
    return destination;
  }
```

Comment: i have tried your code and still same problem, it gives an error "Could not get any response" when updating other values and unchecking (postman)  the "image" in order to keep old value, and also when unchecking any of the other values it converts to null, basicly same results as mine, here what i have added to your code                                
        let mergedObject= 
     {numTel:req.body.numTel,name:req.body.name,lastName:req.body.lastName,email:r 
    eq.body.email,image:req.file.originalname,password:req.body.password}

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you are fetching all the values from `req.body` and passing it to `$set`, so I think when you don't send a value for a particular field it defaults to null and hence all values are updated to null.

If you don't want other values to change to `null`, you must fetch the previous values from the collection, populate in your form, so it will be accessible in `req.body`when you submit. In postman you must pass the existing values along with the ones you want to update OR don't pass the value to `$set` if it's null.

If you don't want to do either of the 2, then another way would be :

```
sellermodel.findById({
   _id: req.params.id
}, function (err, docs) {
   if(err){ do something }
   else{
     let name = req.body.name,
         lastName = req.body.lastName,
         email = req.body.email,
         password = req.body.password;
     if(name == null || name == ''){
        name = docs.name;
     }
     if(lastName == null || lastName == ''){
        lastName = docs.lastName;
     }
     if(email == null || email == ''){
        email = docs.email ;
     }
     if(password == null || password == ''){
        password = docs.password;
     }

     //then your options will look like
     let options;
     if(req.file != undefined){
      options = {
         name: name,
         lastName: lastName,
         email: email,
         password: password,
         image: req.file.originalname
      }
     } else {
      //Not passing the image here will not change the existing value in your document.
      options = {
         name: name,
         lastName: lastName,
         email: email,
         password: password
      }
     }
     //your update query
     sellermodel.updateOne({_id: req.params.id},{$set:options}, 
     function (err,data) {
       if (err) {
         res.json({ msg: 'product not found'+err })
       } else {
         res.json({ msg: 'product updated successfully'+data} )
       }
     })
   }
})
```

In case of `req.file.originalname`, it will obviously throw the error you showed in one of your screenshots as req.file is not defined because you are not passing anything. I suggest you define your options to update the way. I have shown above.